# C# How to divide a number get the result in the format hh:mm:ss:<remainder>

Tags: c#

I want the value of division by the following format:

`hh:mm:ss:ff`

where `ff` is the reminder
eg:

63 divide by 25

`00:00:02:13`

How to achieve this?

Actually `63` is the duration of a video played and `25` is the frames per second rate. I would like to know how long is the duration of the video in the above format?
Currently I am using `string.format()`... methods to achieve this.

Here is what I achieved but my question is to find a better way of doing this.

```
long x = 1513;
long offset = x%25;
long totalSeconds = (x-offset)/25;
long hours = totalSeconds/(3600);
long minutes = (totalSeconds%(3600))/(60);
long seconds = totalSeconds%60;
Console.WriteLine("hours=="+hours);
Console.WriteLine("minutes=="+minutes);
Console.WriteLine("Seconds=="+seconds);
Console.WriteLine("Offset=="+offset);
```

Thanks

Comment: By using code and math.  Show us what you've tried so far...

Comment: Did you even try *anything*?

Comment: Why would the value be 00:00:02:13 rather than 02:13:00:00? What are the original values being divided?

Comment: Does `hh:mm:ss:ff` actually apply to 24/60/60/100 or how is "one hour" for instance indicated?

Comment: What would you get if you divide 101 by 102?

Comment: So you are saying you have 63 frames played at 25 frames per second?

Comment: Yes. you are right.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I am not asking the question without trying anything. Ignore the question is you doesn't want to answer. Thanks

Comment: So 63 frames at 25 fps is 63 / 25 seconds which is 2 seconds with a remainder of 13 / 25. 13 / 25 is (13 * 100 / 25) = 52 hundredths of a second.

Comment: I don't even know why people just love to hate rather than to understand. Even if the OP said `ff` is the reminder, there still exists *What would you get if you divide 101 by 102?* and *So 63 frames at 25 fps is 63 / 25 seconds which is 2 seconds with a remainder of 13 / 25. 13 / 25 is (13 * 100 / 25) = 52 hundredths of a second.* Seriously. And I won't even mention the misunderstanding of the upvoted comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public string Divide(uint Frames, uint FrameRate)
{
    return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Frames / FrameRate).ToString(@"dd\.hh\:mm\:ss") + ':' + (Frames % FrameRate);
}
```